# shortcode in text widget wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am struggling to put a shortcode in a text widget.
So I added

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

In functions.php with no effect. 
When I add just the shortcode like `[btnsx id="80"]`, quotes are escaped and it goes to

```
[btnsx id=\"80\"]
```

When I add `<?php echo do_shortcode('[btnsx id="80"]'); ?>` it get deleted alltogether from the textarea.
Using Zerif Lite

Comment: And the issue is ?

Comment: I want a button to appear in the widget and it doesn't

Comment: Please show  `btnsx` function definition.

Comment: The issue is not with the button x plugin, its with inability to add any shortcode in text widget